# Getting a let value outside a function

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, let

Hello I'm new at swift programming and i want to get `label` value from `loadData()` to use use for my path (reference) to my database on `dbRef!.child(place+"/placeLabel")`. What I mean?! I read data that are on "Dio Con Dio" node. That happens because the value `place` is `let place = "Dio Con Dio"`. So, my application doesn't load data from "Paradosiako - Panorama" node. I want to load everything from database and i thought that if i could make `place` value to change to the next node, it could read all the data.

```
    import UIKit
    import FirebaseDatabase

    class PlacesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

        //MARK: Properties
        @IBOutlet weak var placesTableView: UITableView!

        //database reference
        var dbRef:FIRDatabaseReference?

        var places = [Places]()

        private var loadedLabels = [String: String]()
        private var loadedRatings = [String: Int]()

        //handler
        var handle:FIRDatabaseHandle?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

            // Loads data to cell.
            loadData()
        }

                private func loadData() {

                let place = "Dio Con Dio"

                dbRef!.child(place+"/placeLabel").observe(.childAdded, with: {
                    (snapshot) in
                    let label = snapshot.value as! String
                    self.updatePlace(snapshot.key, label: label)
                })
                dbRef!.child(place+"/rating").observe(.childAdded, with: {
                    (snapshot) in
                    let rating = snapshot.value as! Int
                    self.updatePlace(snapshot.key, rating: rating)
                })


            }

            private func updatePlace(_ key: String, label: String? = nil, rating: Int? = nil) {
                if let label = label {
                    loadedLabels[key] = label
                }
                if let rating = rating {
                    loadedRatings[key] = rating
                }
                guard let label = loadedLabels[key], let rating = loadedRatings[key] else {
                    return
                }
                if let place = Places(name: label, rating: rating) {
                    places.append(place)
                    placesTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
```

[image: **My Database**]

(This question is a follow up [from this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43954708).)

Comment: Why don't you make `label` either an instance field or make `loadData()` return a `String` type? You could also pass `label` as an `inout` parameter.

Comment: So you want to get a value from e function and then pass it to the label inside loadData?

Comment: basically i want `label` value before it is initialized so i can use it here: `dbRef!.child(place+"/placeLabel")`. i want to assign `label` value to `place` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your *new* database schema, try this instead:

```
private func loadData() {
    dbRef!.observe(.childAdded) {
    (placeSnapshot) in
        print("Adding place \(placeSnapshot.key)...")

        // Load each label on the "placeLabel" list. 
        let labels = placeSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "placeLabel")
        for (key, label) in labels.value as! [String: String] {
            self.updatePlace(key, label: label)
        }

        // Load each rating in the "rating" list. 
        let ratings = placeSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "rating")
        for (key, rating) in ratings.value as! [String: Int] {
            self.updatePlace(key, rating: rating)
        }
    }
}
```

The `updatePlace` function simply *groups* the label and rating properties, of a given place, that were separately loaded by `loadData`.

**Places removal**. Of course, the above code won't handle place removal. To do so, you will need to listen for the `childRemoved` event as well.

Comment: "Dio Con Dio", "Paradosiako - Panorama" are place names in real life. 
It works, but there is an error  everytime i'm adding a new place name in database. Let's say that there is already a rating, placeLabel and comment for Dio Con Dio. If someone adds one more rating, comment and placeLabel for Dio Con Dio in my database it will not crash. Now, if i delete all Dio Con Dio comments, ratings and placeLabels and someone is going to add for the first time a comment, rating and placeLabel for Dio Con Dio it crashes, but it creates that node on my database. Do you understand it?

Comment: [Here is the error.](http://prntscr.com/f8hoap) I didn't have the error with the previous code. But you understood what i wanted to do!

Comment: That error is because your key is empty and you force a match with "!"  You should only try to get the value if your key is not nil and not empty ("")

Comment: @Mozahler Yes but with the previous code i had, it wouldn't crash.

Comment: I understand. Your new code should check to make sure you have a valid key before using it. "If let keyValue = key {}" for example. You shouldn't use "!" Because it can crash. This is an easy fix. Paulo did a great job with  his code, but you need to make it work with your data. (Or try to figure out why you have empty keys.)

Comment: @Mozahler i can't understand the difference between the previous and the new code. If the answer was explained, i could implement the think you say on myself.

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to explain this in a comment, so I'll address your current issue here, but Paulo answered your question, I believe. You could even open a new question on this issue.

Here's the code you're having an issue with:

```
for (key, rating) in ratings.value as! [String: Int] {
            self.updatePlace(key, rating: rating)
        }
```

There's nothing wrong with this code, as long as ratings.value is filled with string: integer pairs. Your error occurs because somehow a there is a key missing. (the runtime found a NSNull, so it couldn't convert the data to a dictionary)

You need to set a breakpoint where you are constructing the array in:

```
placeSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "rating")
```

(which is called ratings here/locally).  If is ok to ignore entries with no key, then skip them and don't append them to your array. But it's more likely you have an error and need to find out why you're adding a null value...

Does that make more sense? Please accept Paulo's answer if he solved an issue, and open a new question with more information about childSnapshot (the code), and someone will be sure help you. (I know I'll try.)

Comment: Thanks for the taking the time to do a follow up on my answer. You analysis seems spot on to me :-)

Comment: @Mozahler I understood your answer thank you. [I made a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023455/retrieve-from-firebase-database-calculating-average)