# Retrieve from firebase database calculating average

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an iOS application that uses placenames and rating for each place. I have already made the thing work. I mean that, I save data to my database and I also can read them. The only problem, is when I read them I want them to load on my tableviewcell, by calculating average for each place. See the screenshots and if you don't understand something, ask me to edit the answer.

**TableView**

[image: TableView]

**Firebase**

[image: Firebase]

**My Code that loads data to tableview**

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class PlacesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var placesTableView: UITableView!
    var dbRef:FIRDatabaseReference?
    var places = [Places]()
    private var loadedLabels = [String: String]()
    private var loadedRatings = [String: Int]()
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        // Loads data to cell.
        loadData()
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {   
        //return the number of rows
        return places.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.


        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PlacesTableViewCell  else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of PlacesTableView Cell.")
        }

        let place = places[indexPath.row]

        cell.placeLabel.text = place.name
        cell.ratingControl.rating = place.rating

        return cell

    }
    private func loadData()
    {
        dbRef!.observe(.childAdded, with: {
            (placeSnapshot) in
            //print("Adding place \(placeSnapshot.key)...")

            let labels = placeSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "placeLabel")

            for (key, label) in labels.value as! [String: String] {
                self.updatePlace(key, label: label)
            }
            let ratings = placeSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "rating")
            for (key, rating) in ratings.value as! [String: Int] {
                self.updatePlace(key, rating: rating)
            }
        })
 }

    private func updatePlace(_ key: String, label: String? = nil, rating: Int? = nil)
    {
        if let label = label {
            loadedLabels[key] = label

        }
        if let rating = rating {
            loadedRatings[key] = rating
        }
        guard let label = loadedLabels[key], let rating = loadedRatings[key] else {
            return
        }
        if let place = Places(name: label, rating: rating) {
            places.append(place)
            placesTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
```

**Places swift**

```
import UIKit

class Places {

    //MARK: Properties

    var name: String
    var rating: Int

    //MARK:Types

    struct PropertyKey {
        static let name = "name"
        static let rating = "rating"
    }

    //MARK: Initialization

    init?(name: String, rating: Int) {
        // Initialize stored properties.
        self.name = name
        self.rating = rating

        // Initialization should fail if there is no name or if the rating is negative.
        // The name must not be empty
        guard !name.isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }

        // The rating must be between 0 and 5 inclusively
        guard (rating >= 0) && (rating <= 5) else {
            return nil
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Are you attempting to get the average rating for a place? If so, that's a matter of reading the rating node for each place and averaging the values of the child nodes;( 2 + 4 + 5) / 3?

Comment: Are there error messages? Is there some code that doesn't work the way it's supposed to?  Instead of showing us all your code, pick one specific thing that is getting in your way and describe it. It's possible that someone who doesn't know fire base can help, for example. Narrow the problem down.

Comment: @Jay yeah this is what i want.

Comment: @Mozahler There is an error in another function not on reading values. When a user and adds a new place, the tableview trying to update and crashes, but if he re-open the app that "new place" is showed correctly on the tableview. That was a problem on my [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959004/getting-a-let-value-outside-a-function) quesiton.

Comment: So is the problem that your code is crashing or is the problem you need to know how to read a node and find the average of a sequence of numbers?

Comment: the average of a sequence of numbers @Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty verbose answer but it will iterate over the child nodes of the rating node and calculate the average

```
let parentRef = self.dbRef.child("Paradosiako - Panorama")

let ratingRef = parentRef.child("rating") // rating node
ratingRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    let count = snapshot.childrenCount
    var total: Double = 0.0
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
        let val = snap.value as! Double
        total += val
    }
    let average = total/Double(count)
    print(average)
})
```

**EDIT**

To iterate over all the places and get the averages, here's the code

```
let placesRef = self.dbRef.child("akapnapp")

placesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

    for child in snapshot.children {

        let placeSnap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
        let ratingsSnap = placeSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "rating")

        let count = ratingsSnap.childrenCount
        var total: Double = 0.0
        for child in ratingsSnap.children {
            print(child)
            let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
            let val = snap.value as! Double
            total += val
        }
        let average = total/Double(count)
        print(average)
    }
})
```

and the output showing the code works correctly. My child nodes were named a,b,c instead of the childByAutoId in the question but it works either way.

```
Snap (a) 3
Snap (b) 3
3.0
Snap (a) 2
Snap (b) 4
Snap (c) 5
3.67
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, compiler says `PlacesTableViewController has no member 'ref'`

Comment: self.ref is a reference to your firebase database i.e. ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(). In your case it seems to be called dbRef. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Jay She needs to do that for every place on her database.

Comment: @AlexAndreadis Thanks. I knew that but thought the OP could extrapolate from my code snippet. Updated the answer for compelteness.

Comment: @RoulaChiouma I updated my answer and wrote the code for you. It will iterate over all of the places in your main database node and calculate the averages.

Comment: @RoulaChiouma It does! I copy and pasted it directly from my own project using the exact same Firebase structure in your question. I also copy and pasted the output so you could see it's working. Note that my structure had *ratings* and yours is *rating* so I updated my code to match your structure.

Answer (score 1):

As i understood you want to have a rounded double for your application and not a double. Just change the code inside your `loadData()` function and it would work for you. Also you will call `updatePlace()` as you did.  Please approve Jay's answer, he wrote the code.

```
private func loadData()
{
    dbRef!.observe(.childAdded, with: {
        (placeSnapshot) in
    let parentRef = self.dbRef?.child(placeSnapshot.key)
    let ratingRef = parentRef?.child("rating")
    ratingRef?.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        let count = snapshot.childrenCount
        var total: Double = 0.0
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
            let val = snap.value as! Double
            total += val
        }
        let average = total/Double(count)
        print("Average for \(placeSnapshot.key) = \(Int(round(average)))")

        self.updatePlace("" , label: placeSnapshot.key, rating: Int(round(average)))

    })
    })

}
```

Comment: Why is there a second observe inside the first? The .childAdded will return everything in the node so the ratings will already be in the snapshot.

Comment: this will return the average rating for every place. For ex., 
Average for Markiz = 3 
Average for Paradosiako - Panorama = 3

Comment: Not what I meant. The results node is contained in the placeSnapshot so there's no reason to hit the database again to get that same data.

Comment: @Jay Okay understood :) !