# Calculating Averages From Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, d3.js, firebase-realtime-database, average

there is a calculating an average from [Firebase example already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023455/retrieve-from-firebase-database-calculating-average), however, I'm not able to work out my own solution from it (I'm new to.. everything!)

This is how I'm saving to Firebase:

```js
function sentvar() {
    var CareerMpd = firebase.database().ref("career/");

    CareerMpd.push({
        Career: {
            manuv: document.getElementById('manuv').value,
            sengv: document.getElementById('sengv').value,
            contv: document.getElementById('contv').value,
            archv: document.getElementById('archv').value,
            bengv: document.getElementById('bengv').value,
            projv: document.getElementById('projv').value,
            quntv: document.getElementById('quntv').value,
            techv: document.getElementById('techv').value,
            cengv: document.getElementById('cengv').value,
            facav: document.getElementById('facav').value,
            outsv: document.getElementById('outsv').value,
            manue: document.getElementById('manue').value,
            senge: document.getElementById('senge').value,
            conte: document.getElementById('conte').value,
            arche: document.getElementById('arche').value,
            benge: document.getElementById('benge').value,
            proje: document.getElementById('proje').value,
            qunte: document.getElementById('qunte').value,
            teche: document.getElementById('teche').value,
            cenge: document.getElementById('cenge').value,
            facae: document.getElementById('facae').value,
            outse: document.getElementById('outse').value
        }
    });
```

This works fine!

Some context might be useful here. These are variables for a D3 Radar Chart/results of a survey and I want to read the averages of these to put into the rendered D3 Chart.

Example. How do I read all of the values of manuv (a child of Career)?

Here is a sample of a query output from firebase:

[Link to console screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC5Tt.png)

Comment: What do you mean by `all of the values of manuv`? If I understand your structure correctly you are going to have a single value at `career/Career/manuv`.

Comment: Thanks @VivekAthalye for taking a look. I have many instances of the career parameter as survey respondents. I'll adapt the question to include a query of the firebase